# How to using post method to download csv file using Papaparse？

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I want to request the file using “POST” Method? Any suggestion?

```
url = "https://www.xxxx.com/data.csv";
Papa.parse(url, {
  download: true,
  complete: function() {
    // executed after all files are complete
  }
});
```